# Weird behaviour when trying to print characters of a byte string

Tags: python

Why this short code behaves differently from a run to other?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
for c in 'aɣyul':
    print c
```

The outputs that I have in each run are:

```
# nothing
---
a
---
l
---
u
l
---
a
y
u
l
...etc
```

I know how to solve the problem, the question is just why Python prints a different part of the string, instead of the same part, at each run?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `u` at leading of your string which make that python treads with your string as an unicode, and decode your character while printing:

```
>>> for c in u'aɣyul':
...     print c
... 
a
ɣ
y
u
l
```

Note that without encoding python will break the unicode character in two separate hex value and in each print you will get the string representation of this hex values:

```
>>> 'aɣyul'
'a\xc9\xa3yul'
    ^   ^
```

If you want to know that why python break the unicode to 2 hex value that's because of that instances of    `str` contain raw 8-bit values while a unicode character used more than 8 bit memory.

You can also decode the hex values manually:

```
>>> print '\xc9\xa3'.decode('utf8')
ɣ
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I know how to solve the problem. I just want an explanation of the behavior when looping over a byte string in python.